# Jboss logging - how to limit un-known classes?

Tags: logging, jboss, log4j, slf4j, jboss6.x

My STDOUT / console output in Eclipse is being flooded by lines like:

```
12:05:37,395 INFO  [STDOUT] 2163 [RMI TCP Connection(1)-127.0.0.1] DEBUG org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet - Processing extensions for '/getFare'
```

What entry can I put in jboss-logging.xml (jboss level, or app-level) to hide these error messages?

Do I need to use some kind of special fancy filter / pattern matching?

I already have the following entry in jboss-logging.xml, that I thought would limited the org.apache error messages:

```
<logger category="org.apache">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
```

I have successfully set up per-application logging, by placing a separate jboss-logging.xml file in the EAP/META-INF directly. It's contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<logging xmlns="urn:jboss:logging:6.0" xmlns:b="urn:jboss:bean-deployer:2.0">
    <define-context name="myapp"/>
    <logger category="com.myproject.myClass"><level name="DEBUG"/></logger>
</logging>
```

An example of how that class is being logged to STDOUT:

```
12:06:00,075 WARN  [com.myproject.myClass] THIS IS A CUSTOM WARNING MESSAGE FROM ONE OF MY PROJECTS .JAVA CLASS FILES
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same problem with INFO [STDOUT] types of messages.  Using a logging filter like this worked great:

```
<logger category="STDOUT">
    <level name="WARN"/>
</logger>
```